# How to make new dataframe from existing dataframe by removing duplicates from columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **'merged_df'** that looks like this:

| Login ID | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| cab001 | 4 |
| cab002 | 3 |
| cab001 | 4 |
| cab003 | 2 |

There are many duplicates in the **login_id** column. I want to make another dataframe with only unique 'login_id' and the sum of 'volume' for each unique 'login_id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this get you what you want?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'login_id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'Volumn' : [10, 10, 20, 20, 50]
})

df_new = df.groupby('login_id', as_index = False)['Volumn'].sum().sort_values('Volumn', ascending = False)
```

Comment: the new_df comes out to be series and not dataframe, and can you sort it on sum of volume?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect what I believe you were going for. This will keep the data as a dataframe and provides the option of how you can sort it (ascending = False or ascending = True)

Comment: Thanks, for understanding my problem and providing the required solution.

Comment: can you make a bar diagram from the top 10 rows of df_new? X -axis = login_id and Y-axis = volume.

Comment: I don’t know as much about metplot or graphs as a I should :/ if you need help with that you might start with my code and ask with those tags. I just don’t want to lead you in the wrong direction haha